# Internationalization of p-calendar (primeNg + i18next)

Tags: angular, typescript, calendar, primeng, i18next

I am using the internationalization-framework called i18next. One of my components is a p-calendar but I don't know how to internationalize it with this framework. Does anyone know how I can internationalize this component with i18next? If someone knows another solution without using i18next, I can also use.

- Angular version: 8.2
- PrimeNG version: 8.1.1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### UPDATE for PrimeNG version >= 11

Use the i18N API for newer versions of PrimeNG.

Create a translation file such as "en.json".

```
{
"primeng": {
    "dayNames": ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    "dayNamesShort": ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
    "dayNamesMin": ["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],
    "monthNames": ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
    "monthNamesShort": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    "today": "Today",
    "weekHeader": "Wk"
}
```

And include the file in your app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { PrimeNGConfig } from 'primeng/api';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    constructor(private config: PrimeNGConfig, private translateService: TranslateService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
    }

    translate(lang: string) {
        this.translateService.use(lang);
        this.translateService.get('primeng').subscribe(res => this.config.setTranslation(res));
    }
}
```

Check out the [official documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/i18n).

#### OLD (PrimeNG version < 11)

For the PrimeNG calendar you can add localization over the locale property.

**HTML**:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateValue" [locale]="en"></p-calendar>
```

**TS**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.en = {
        firstDayOfWeek: 0,
        dayNames: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
        dayNamesShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
        dayNamesMin: ["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],
        monthNames: [ "January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December" ],
        monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ],
        today: 'Today',
        clear: 'Clear',
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        weekHeader: 'Wk'
    };
}
```

Check out the [official documentation](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/calendar).

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want to internationalize my application with i18next or maybe another method. Would you know how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know i18next. My answer refers to an alternative solution.

Comment: Umm okey. And if I want to set another language with your method, how would I do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Somewhere in a central location I would define an object for the calendar with different languages like `lang = { en: {first day of the week: ... }, it: {first day of week: ...} }`.Not sure, but I think it should be possible to get the current language from your i18next tool. Then you could do something like this:
`<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateValue" [locale]="lang[i18next.getCurrentLang]"></p-calendar>`

Comment: [locale] is no longer functioning in V11.  Use i18n.

Comment: Do you have an example of where this works with another language, other than English? (In angular 11)

Comment: The above solution works for me. But I need to call the translate method inside ngOninit and pass the JSON file name. For English
```this.translate("en");```
And for Bengali use this.
```this.translate("bn")```;